# How to skip rows from resultset in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

i am working with search function and pagination.

heres my code for search function

```
if( isset($_POST['searchBut']) ) {

        $name = $_POST['inputSearch'];
        $pageSearch = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

        //lets say there are 10 items selected with this query
        $searchQuery = "SELECT name,image,price,description FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' ";

        $result = $db->query($searchQuery);

        //getting total rows
        $fetchTotalRow = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //getting total pages
        $totalPages = ceil($fetchTotalRow / $perPage);

        $links = "";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
                $links .= ($i != $pageSearch )  ? "<li><a href='collections.php?page=$i'>Page $i</span></a></li> " : "<li class='active'><a href='collections.php?page=$i'>Page $pageSearch</a></li> ";
        }
}
```

now how do i limit my page to only 9 items in first page, and the last one will be on second page. 
i've succesfully apply this to normal pagination with LIMIT($start,$offset) function, but this is for database, how to do this with resultset ?

Comment: Use LIMIT in your query, I can't see limit in your search query..... You need help for limit...!

Comment: why would i use limit when i need to search the entire database for items with certain name and include them to resultset and work from there

Comment: Then do the same as you done for normal listing, how pagination is working in normal listing as per that the search listing is work...

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Hope this is you need...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`LIMIT`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) to your query.

```
//page 1
$searchQuery = "SELECT name,image,price,description FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' LIMIT 0, 9";

//page 2
$searchQuery = "SELECT name,image,price,description FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' LIMIT 1, 9";
```

MySQL will search the entire set first and then only return the specified LIMIT. LIMIT does not search only the first 9 posts...

Answer (score 0):

Use **LIMIT 0,9** or **LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0**

In your case,

```
$pageSearch = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$pageOffset = $pageSearch - 1;

$limitQuery = "LIMIT $pageOffset , 9 ";

//lets say there are 10 items selected with this query
$searchQuery = "SELECT name,image,price,description FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' " . $limitQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **LIMIT** for that. You have to use LIMIT like `LIMIT ".($pageSearch-1).", ".$perPage` that's all.... Do as below:

```
$searchQuery = "SELECT name,image,price,description FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%' LIMIT ".($pageSearch-1).", ".$perPage;
```